Is coverage error in scikit learn one point higher than initial formula?
I have implemented a BP_MLL neural network and used scikit learn's coverage error function as a metric for the network. The output of the network for this metric is one point higher than the results in the base paper.
Also in the website it is mentioned that: "Note: Our implementation’s score is 1 greater than the one given in Tsoumakas et al., 2010. This extends it to handle the degenerate case in which an instance has 0 true labels."
Based on this should I subtract 1 from the output for coverage error to get results based on "Tsoumakas et al., 2010." ?
